# Gpay option not showing in stripe checkout popup

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout

i have been trying since morning to have the checkout popup show me GPAY option but it looks like it is not working, could you guys take a look what is wrong with it

`

```
<form>
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="<PUBLIC_KEY>" 
data-amount="999" 
data-name="Business Name" 
data-image="https://example.com/img/logo.png"
data-locale="auto"
data-currency="usd"
data-zip-code="true"
data-allow-remember-me="false"
data-billing-address="true"
data-Shipping-address="true"
data-panel-label="Pay"
data-label="Pay with Google Pay"
data-description="Example charge"
data-apple-pay="false" 
data-google-pay="true"
></script>
</form>`
```

i tried with enabling google play and disabling card option as well

Answer (score 0):

You are using Legacy version of checkout, which doesn't support Google Pay. You should [migrate](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) to the new Checkout.